# html- search using a dropdown box?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I'm currently working on a website. I can search my database using inputbox tags, but I'm also looking to be able to search the database using a drop-down box. Not sure why it won't work. Any help would be a appreciated???. Thanks. (Database is MS Access).

**Dropdown box code:**

```
<td>
 <select>
  <option name="reason">Please Select...</option>
  <option name="reason">Sick</option>
  <option name="reason">Holiday</option>
 </select>
</td>
```

Comment: I put the solved solution up in case someone else has the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**[Solved}**

My '*name*' attribute needs to be in the select tag, not the options tag.

```
<select name="reason">
  <option>Please Select...</option>
  <option value="Sick">Sick</option>
  <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
 </select>
```